# Showing phpMyAdmin Database on a web interface

Tags: interface, phpmyadmin

I have created my database with phpMyAdmin (customer information).
I will update the database by importing new csv files.

Now i want to set up a webpage/ user interface for this database with all information, where i can see all information like the tracking number, adresses and so on. What is the best method for my "idea" ?

Answer (score 0):

By the way my solution was "editablegrid" from http://www.editablegrid.net/en/

Using phpmyAdmin as database and a clear interface with options to edit the rows.